# C# CURL POST(Content-Type, Hash key)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, post, dotnet-httpclient

I am currently trying to send POST request in C# (API), but I have some troubles with Content Type and Authorization, because its in format apiHash, apiKey.

Curl example:

```
curl -i -XPOST https://sandboxapi.g2a.com/v1/order \
-H "Authorization: qdaiciDiyMaTjxMt, 74026b3dc2c6db6a30a73e71cdb138b1e1b5eb7a97ced46689e2d28db1050875" \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{"product_id": "10000027819004", "max_price": 45.0}'
```

Documentation for API:
https://www.g2a.com/integration-api/documentation/#api-Orders-AddOrder

And this is my code so far:

```
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

public async Task < string > makeRequest() {
    var values = new Dictionary < string,
        string > {
            {
                "product_id",
                "10000027819004"
            },
            {
                "max_price",
                "45.0"
            }
        };

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

    AuthenticationHeaderValue authHeaders = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("qdaiciDiyMaTjxMt", "74026b3dc2c6db6a30a73e71cdb138b1e1b5eb7a97ced46689e2d28db1050875");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = authHeaders;

    var response = await client.PostAsync("https://sandboxapi.g2a.com/v1/order", content);

    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return responseString;
}
```

I tried multiple solutions, but I seem to be unable to have it all correct together(Content-Type, Authorization and parameters).

Comment: What's the response when you perform POST?

Comment: Currently its Content-Type Header empty or not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You must set the content type like this :

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders
  .Accept
  .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

This will solve the issue.

Comment: Please tell when you try it.

Comment: Hello, tried it, but it still says Content-Type header empty or not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending `FormUrlEncodedContent` which is not JSON while the curl example is sending JSON.

Refactor your method to use actual serialized JSON string in a `StringContent` with proper content type set.

```
public async Task<string> makeRequest() {
    var values = new {
        product_id = "10000027819004",
        max_price = 45.0
    };

    //-d '{"product_id": "10000027819004", "max_price": 45.0}'
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values); //using Json.Net
    var content = new StringContent(json);

    var auth = "qdaiciDiyMaTjxMt, 74026b3dc2c6db6a30a73e71cdb138b1e1b5eb7a97ced46689e2d28db1050875";
    //-H "Authorization: qdaiciDiyMaTjxMt, 74026b3dc2c6db6a30a73e71cdb138b1e1b5eb7a97ced46689e2d28db1050875" \
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", auth);
    //-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");

    var response = await client.PostAsync("https://sandboxapi.g2a.com/v1/order", content);

    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return responseString;
}
```

Comment: Hello, I have just tried it, but it still says Content-Type header empty or not allowed.

Comment: The code provided is accurate so only thing left is to check the raw requests being sent by the two approaches and see what is the difference.

Comment: Still not working, but its weird, I have checked and Content-Type is in header now.                                                                                                               
`code` Headers:
{
  Authorization: qdaiciDiyMaTjxMt, 74026b3dc2c6db6a30a73e71cdb138b1e1b5eb7a97ced46689e2d28db1050875
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Content-Length: 48
}`code`

Comment: @Restr i removed the UTF encoding to see if that makes a difference.